# Ductwork: redesign supply from flex to rigid

Tags: hvac, ducts

I’m in the midst of a project to make my basement space more usable, a big part of which will involve shuffling ductwork as it appears to have been installed (during the previous owner’s tenure) with reckless disregard for humans over 5’ 6”….

The section of supply I’m currently trying to address is all flex duct with two “hubs” (dunno the official word) from which there are runs to registers.

I’m thinking of switching to rigid round duct with takeoffs located close to the respective registers. I’m going with rigid since it’ll look better exposed in the basement (which I’ll be finishing), sit tighter to the joists for headroom, and hopefully will also perform better.

Refer to my sketch for the current setup and my best guess at what’ll work with rigid. The biggest design change is that I’d split the run to have rooms B and C start from the trunk rather than branch off room A (rooms B/C get poor airflow today). I have a ? for the size of the new duct supplying those rooms - thinking 6” might be sufficient?

[image: duct redesign sketch]

I’m exactly 0% an hvac pro, so by all means educate me on what I’m neglecting/alternative approaches/etc.

Obligatory: I’ve gotten quotes to redo all the ductwork and they were way out of budget, so I’m really hoping to make some improvements on my own. I’m a tenured construction DIYer and aim for code compliance + as-close-to-best-practice-as-I-can-get in my projects.

Thanks, people of the internet!

**EDIT 1**: as requested, I’m adding some photos of the branch of duct in question along with a sketch of the full system (supply only) for added context if helpful. The colors in the sketch correlate to the colored ducts in the photos. Fun puzzle.

The left side (branch supplied by a 10” flex - labeled “new work”) is the part of the system I’ve already converted to a (mostly) rigid duct setup. It’s not fully finished so I’m open to any suggestions on that side, too. The 12” line feeds two registers in an addition from the 90’s but that ductwork is buried so I’m not sure of sizing…but that room gets ample (probably too much) air, today.

[image: Exhibit D: more shoddy sketches of full supply system]

[image: start of branch]

[image: first stop: a hub feeding bedroom 1]

[image: duct from first hub to second]

[image: next stop: a hub feeding bedroom 2 and bathroom]

Comment: Where crossing under joists, a flattish rectangular duct can have more flow area than a round duct for equivalent headroom...or more headroom for equivalent flow.

Comment: The IRC specs a minimum ceiling height of 6'-4" at ducts (and beams and girders). It's 7'-0" everywhere else (actually not, but 7'-0" is safe).

Comment: Your arrow pointing from the end of the trunk is alarming. There shouldn't be any duct coming off the trunk within a foot or two of its end.

Comment: There's a duct systems IRC chapter, https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2021P2/chapter-16-duct-systems. THREE SCREWS!

Comment: The “trunk” is far from to scale…just meant to be representative of where this branch begins. There’s a sizable and complex set of ductwork coming off the air handler I ignored in the sketch. It might technically not even be a “trunk” based design…more of a “spider”. This is just one of the four main branches…

Comment: Unless you have unusually high pressure/air-flow from your air-handler upstream and/or some sort of inline booster fan arrangement, 4" ducting for HVAC seems unrealistically optimistic.

Comment: Three screws? yeah, keep hoping there buddy. - A "0% an hvac pro" ain't doing this in rectangle, but that's what it should be. And it needs to start back at the plenum chamber (which is a mess). Otherwise you're just swapping flex for ridged, which is good but not enough. You got a 7 feeding a 6 and two 4s that wouldn't work anyway. That should be like 14x7 feeding two 13x3s - quote was 10k because it's like 3k in stuff when a single transition is 80 bucks these days. **?** = no less than half the size of the trunk, up to same size as.

Comment: *Rigid because it’ll look better exposed in the basement* - 24x5 inside a soffit would be even better. Pictures?

Comment: The registers with 4” ducts are definitely not performing well right now. 

I considered going with rectangular ductwork for even better headroom but for the life of me couldn’t figure out where to source it as a non-pro. Quote was more like 16-18k (2k sq ft house). Though I’d happily pay 5k for “stuff” and a design and DIY it over 6 months. 

I’ll grab some visuals this evening and update the post. I might also try and sketch the full system for better context…

Comment: @mazura updated with images and sketches galore.

Comment: You've already gotten quotes, that's good. Were they detailed? If so, they would have spec'd the duct sizing right there in the quote. Just use that. Oh, and don't forget, you're paying _retail_ for the supplies, they're getting them wholesale, and you won't have heat/AC for days/weeks while you work on this project, while they'll get the whole thing done in a day or three. Be sure to factor that into your pricing equation. I'm all for DIY, just not doing DIY because it's "cheaper" without all the factors in place. (Says the guy who is ruing his DIY addition that still isn't complete...)

Comment: @FreeMan Unfortunately, no - the quotes were incredibly generic…”remove the old, replace with new, seal it up”. 

You bring up all good factors to consider, but I’m already neck deep in a piecemeal basement finish-out so adding a piecemeal HVAC update fits (uncomfortably) right in! Coming from a guy who rued the DIY addition to his last house for many, many months. 

If it proves just too complicated to sort out on my own I may well have to hire it out at some point…but, hard way first…right??

Comment: For posterity: I’m thinking my attempt will be replacing the section in question with what I’ll call a “sub trunk” of 10x7 rect (that or 12x5…) that’ll run the full length of the house (top to bottom on the diagram). From that duct I’ll pull off perpendicular runs of flex for each of the registers and tuck those between joists (which run left to right in the diagram). 

Wish me luck!

Comment: I’ll probably also look at sizing up the 4” runs to 6” while I’m at it. And think about reducing (or adding a damper to) the big 12” run since that part of the system gets far more air than necessary right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don’t have the “right” answer (because HVAC ducting seems as much art as science), here’s the approach I settled on:

I’m thinking my attempt will be replacing the section in question with what I’ll call a “sub trunk” of 12x5 duct that’ll run the full length of the house (top to bottom on the diagram). From that duct I’ll pull off perpendicular runs of flex for each of the registers and tuck those between joists.

Comment: Yeah, going with a rigid sub-trunk instead of flex spaghetti is definitely a good move.  Hopefully you'll be able to come back in and address the rest of the ductopus in the future :)   Also, don't forget to make sure that the lining on the flex you are installing is fully stretched!

Comment: Appreciate the vote of confidence @ThreePhaseEel! The next round will be sorting through the returns. They’re arguably worse. Good news is I found a local sheet metal guy so the world of custom sizes and transitions is now wide open…which may be dangerous. We shall see!